# Creating a random signature

Tags: java, security, random, digital-signature

I'm trying to calculate the signature of a document using the method `initSign(PrivateKey privateKey, SecureRandom random)`. 
Before calling the method, I istantiated an object:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
```

but when I call the method multiple times with the same key, it gives me always the same signature instead of randomizing it, even if the random number changes time by time.
Why?

Comment: For the off topic vote: why would you need the code to answer this? I don't see how this cannot be answered without code, the description is clear enough (to me anyway). That said, currently I'm not sure about the signature format so code would certainly be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you are using one of the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding schemes. These are created using one of MD2withRSA, MD5withRSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA512withRSA. However, none of these schemes take a random as parameter. RSA / PSS does, but it is not included in the standard API (you could use the Bouncy Castle provider though). ECDSA also uses a random for generating the signatures.

The Java Cryptography Architecture defines classes like the `Signature` class for general use. That means that there will be methods and arguments that are not applicable for certain algorithms. In your case the RSA PKCS v1.5 signature generation simply ignores the random as it doesn't need it.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Signature pss = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA/PSS");
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    // not random: random.setSeed(new byte[16]);
    pss.initSign(generatedKeyPair.getPrivate(), random);
    pss.update("owlstead".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    byte[] sig = pss.sign();
    System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(sig));
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't this answer your question? Is there anything missing or don't you understand what is meant by the answer?